# Why is value_counts()[:10] throwing an error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count

I have a column of a floating point integer index,

```
file['Id'].dtypes => dtype('float64')
```

While counting the top values, it doesn't throw an error, but if I try to retrieve top 10 index, it's throwing a value error:

```
counts = pd.DataFrame(file['Id'].value_counts().copy(deep = True)) -> no error
counts = pd.DataFrame(file['Id'].value_counts()[:10].copy(deep = True)) -> error

ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing   
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: We'd need to see the data through a [mcve]

Comment: @rafaelc Here's the count index for what was working correctly: 

ID(1002.0, 5797.0, 2054.0, ...): Count(4278, 403, 294, ..)